# Error in hexadecimal conversion to base58-btc

Tags: perl, base-conversion

I am using the conversion algorithm of http://lenschulwitz.com/base58 , [this perl code](http://lenschulwitz.com/b58/base58perl.txt).

- MANY GOOD CONVERSIONS, AS: `18e559fc6cb0e8de2ce8b50007d474a0d886208e698a07948671e0df520c1525` was converted to `2gBdDRXoLPEhgf9Zd7zw5ujK1qcoPZoendBQJ22VjgqS`, **all 44 digits**.
- **BAD** CONVERSION: `0ab3de5e16675aeb0c4831f5218901fec56f39cc8ad16e5559be4a0ee211f5d0` was converted to `in9v3fi1cntD6ERD6QryMJq4r5BncjYZ32xZA6Uj4ST`, 43 digits!
- other BAD: `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d0` to `11111111111111111111111111111114b`

What is wrong with the Perl code? 
I can use some kind of padding in base58-btc?

---

PS: I can use something as `sudo apt-get install libbase58-0`  that [is reliable at UBUNTU](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/libbase58-0)... But need a  Perl interface for it.

Comment: How do you know it's wrong?  Your second input is smaller...

Comment: @aschepler No, check by yourself, both inputs are 64 hexadecimal digits.

Comment: @aschepler I edited with more one example

Answer (score 0):

Rather than debugging that poorly laid-out code, I suggest that you install [`Encode::Base58`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Base58)
or
[`Encode::Base58::GMP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Base58::GMP)

Both of those modules have maintainers who will answer questions if you find you are getting incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

Tested with other conversors, as [bs58 js lib](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58), all producing same and consistent results.

It seems [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/250659#250659)... perhaps the real question is "base58 bitcoin use fixed size representation?"  Can I use something as pad 1s?

But it is also part of the answer, not edited the question (reverted) and proced an answer.

---

... It is a conversion *between "incompatible" bases* (!), so I think is impossible
... `58=2*29` is not a multiple of `16=2^4`... only when digits are multiple of 2...  But:

- base50("E") = hex("0D"); base58("1E") = hex("000D"); ... the number of padding digits are converted as multiple...
- what the problem of cut/add for padding? base50("E") = hex("D"); base58("1E") = hex("D");  base50("E")=hex("000000D"); base50("1111111111E")=hex("D"); ... Not seems a problem, so padding-algorithm (fill 0s or 1s) can be used.

SOLUTION: ok, lets pad, fill 1s when converted have less than 44 digits.